# Как правильно перенести калькулятор в MysQL

Tags: mysql, vue.js

[image: Калькулятор превью]

Имеется калькулятор, возможно ли перенести и заполнять данные в нем из БД MYSQL, в данный момент все данные хранятся в файле vue_calc.js, использовался ранее на HTML сайте. Сейчас сайт переезжает на Laravel, и хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы данные брались из БД, и изменялись в админке сайта.

У каждого дня недели свои данные, то есть в понедельник с 3 до 7 утра на своем автомобиле работа будет стоить 1250 рублей, во вторник данные уже иные 1430 рублей. Но так же всё зависит и от колонки тип автомобиля, так как на арендном в понедельник 1250 рублей, на своём же сумма эта меньше 1150 рублей.

```js
Vue.component('time-picker', {
template: `
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="fromTime" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">С</label>
            <select v-model = "activeFrom" @change="changeHandler()" class="form-control col-sm-3" id="fromTime" >
                <option v-for="time in fromIntervals">{{time}}</option>
            </select>
            <label for="toTime" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">до</label>
            <select v-model= "activeTo" @change="changeHandler()" class="form-control col-sm-3" id="toTime">
                <option v-for="time in toIntervals">{{time}}</option>
            </select>
            <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                    <button
                        v-if="addPickerButtonVisable"
                        @click="addPicker()"
                        type="button"
                        class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm"
                        data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-placement="top"
                        title="Добавить время"
                    >
                        <svg width="22px" height="22px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-plus-circle" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H4a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3.5V4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V12a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8z"/>
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1a7 7 0 0 0 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <button
                        v-if= "removePickerButtonVisable"
                        @click="removePicker()"
                        type="button"
                        class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"
                        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                        title="Убрать время"
                    >
                        <svg width="22px" height="22px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-x-circle" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1a7 7 0 0 0 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M11.854 4.146a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-7 7a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l7-7a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.146 4.146a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708l7 7a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708l-7-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0z"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`,
props: ['uid', 'removePickerButtonVisable', 'addPickerButtonVisable', 'day'],
data () {
    return {
        activeFrom: 0,
        activeTo: 0,
    }
},
methods: {
    addPicker() {
        this.$emit('add-picker')
    },
    removePicker() {
        this.$emit('remove-picker', this.uid)
    },
    changeHandler() {
        if (this.activeFrom != 0 && this.activeTo != 0)
        this.$emit('date-picked', { activeFrom:this.activeFrom, activeTo:this.activeTo, id:this.uid, day:this.day})
    }
},
computed: {
    toIntervals() {
        if (this.activeFrom == 0) return [];
        if (this.activeFrom == '00:00') return ['00:00'];

        let avList = [];
        let start = +this.activeFrom.slice(0,2); // get hours val

        if ((start+1) < 10) {
            for (let i = (start+1); i < 10; i++) avList.push(`0${i}:00`);
            for (let i = 10; i < 24; i++) avList.push(`${i}:00`);
        } else {
            for (let i = (start+1); i < 24; i++) avList.push(`${i}:00`);
        }

        return avList;
    },
    fromIntervals () {
        let ar = [];
        for (let i = 00; i < 10; i++) ar.push(`0${i}:00`);
        for (let i = 10; i < 24; i++) ar.push(`${i}:00`);
        return ar;
    }
}

});

Vue.component('time-picker-group', {
template: `
    <div class="border-bottom">
        <p>{{name}}</p>
        <time-picker
            :day="day"
            v-for="picker in datePickerInfo"
            :uid="picker.id"
            :key="picker.id"
            :add-picker-button-visable="addPickerButtonVisable"
            :remove-picker-button-visable="removePickerButtonVisable"
            @date-picked="changePicker"
            @add-picker="addPicker"
            @remove-picker="removePicker"
        ></time-picker>
    </div>
`,
props: ['day', 'name'],
data () {
    return {
        pickerIdCounter: 0, // необходим для обеспечения уникальности пикеров времени
        datePickerInfo: [
            {id:0, from: -1, to: -1}
        ],
    }
},
computed: {
    removePickerButtonVisable() {
        // если два и больше разрешаем удалять
        return this.datePickerInfo.length > 1;
    },
    addPickerButtonVisable() {
        // один и невыбранный
        if ( (this.datePickerInfo.length == 1) && (this.datePickerInfo[0].to == -1)) return false;
        // достигли максимального количества
        if (this.datePickerInfo.length == 4) return false;
        // иначе
        return true;
    }
},
methods: {
    changePicker (event) {
        let obj = this.datePickerInfo.find(item => item.id == event.id);

        obj.from = +event.activeFrom.slice(0,2); // перевод часов в индексы
        obj.to = (event.activeTo == '00:00')? 23 : ((+event.activeTo.slice(0,2)) - 1);


        this.$emit('date-picked', event)
    },
    addPicker() {
        this.datePickerInfo.push({
            id: ++this.pickerIdCounter,
            from: -1,
            to: -1
        });
    },
    removePicker(event) {

        let index;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.datePickerInfo.length; i++) {
            if (this.datePickerInfo[i].id == event) index = i;
        }
        this.datePickerInfo.splice(index, 1);

        this.$emit('date-picker-remove', {day:this.day,id:event});
    },
},
});



var app = new Vue({
el: '#calc',
data () {
    return {
        days : [
            {id:0, text:'Понедельник', active: false, },
            {id:1, text:'Вторник',     active: false, },
            {id:2, text:'Среда',       active: false, },
            {id:3, text:'Четверг',     active: false, },
            {id:4, text:'Пятница',     active: false, },
            {id:5, text:'Суббота',     active: false, },
            {id:6, text:'Воскресенье', active: false, }
        ],
        globalDatePickerInfo: [],
        globalIntervals: [
            [ // Понедельник
                {from: '00', to: '01', busy: false},{from: '01', to: '02', busy: false},{from: '02', to: '03', busy: false},
                {from: '03', to: '04', busy: false},{from: '04', to: '05', busy: false},{from: '05', to: '06', busy: false},
                {from: '06', to: '07', busy: false},{from: '07', to: '08', busy: false},{from: '08', to: '09', busy: false},
                {from: '09', to: '10', busy: false},{from: '10', to: '11', busy: false},{from: '11', to: '12', busy: false},
                {from: '12', to: '13', busy: false},{from: '13', to: '14', busy: false},{from: '14', to: '15', busy: false},
                {from: '15', to: '16', busy: false},{from: '16', to: '17', busy: false},{from: '17', to: '18', busy: false},
                {from: '18', to: '19', busy: false},{from: '19', to: '20', busy: false},{from: '20', to: '21', busy: false},
                {from: '21', to: '22', busy: false},{from: '22', to: '23', busy: false},{from: '23', to: '00', busy: false},
            ], [ // Вторник
                {from: '00', to: '01', busy: false},{from: '01', to: '02', busy: false},{from: '02', to: '03', busy: false},
                {from: '03', to: '04', busy: false},{from: '04', to: '05', busy: false},{from: '05', to: '06', busy: false},
                {from: '06', to: '07', busy: false},{from: '07', to: '08', busy: false},{from: '08', to: '09', busy: false},
                {from: '09', to: '10', busy: false},{from: '10', to: '11', busy: false},{from: '11', to: '12', busy: false},
                {from: '12', to: '13', busy: false},{from: '13', to: '14', busy: false},{from: '14', to: '15', busy: false},
                {from: '15', to: '16', busy: false},{from: '16', to: '17', busy: false},{from: '17', to: '18', busy: false},
                {from: '18', to: '19', busy: false},{from: '19', to: '20', busy: false},{from: '20', to: '21', busy: false},
                {from: '21', to: '22', busy: false},{from: '22', to: '23', busy: false},{from: '23', to: '00', busy: false},
            ], [ // Среда
                {from: '00', to: '01', busy: false},{from: '01', to: '02', busy: false},{from: '02', to: '03', busy: false},
                {from: '03', to: '04', busy: false},{from: '04', to: '05', busy: false},{from: '05', to: '06', busy: false},
                {from: '06', to: '07', busy: false},{from: '07', to: '08', busy: false},{from: '08', to: '09', busy: false},
                {from: '09', to: '10', busy: false},{from: '10', to: '11', busy: false},{from: '11', to: '12', busy: false},
                {from: '12', to: '13', busy: false},{from: '13', to: '14', busy: false},{from: '14', to: '15', busy: false},
                {from: '15', to: '16', busy: false},{from: '16', to: '17', busy: false},{from: '17', to: '18', busy: false},
                {from: '18', to: '19', busy: false},{from: '19', to: '20', busy: false},{from: '20', to: '21', busy: false},
                {from: '21', to: '22', busy: false},{from: '22', to: '23', busy: false},{from: '23', to: '00', busy: false},
            ], [ // Четверг
                {from: '00', to: '01', busy: false},{from: '01', to: '02', busy: false},{from: '02', to: '03', busy: false},
                {from: '03', to: '04', busy: false},{from: '04', to: '05', busy: false},{from: '05', to: '06', busy: false},
                {from: '06', to: '07', busy: false},{from: '07', to: '08', busy: false},{from: '08', to: '09', busy: false},
                {from: '09', to: '10', busy: false},{from: '10', to: '11', busy: false},{from: '11', to: '12', busy: false},
                {from: '12', to: '13', busy: false},{from: '13', to: '14', busy: false},{from: '14', to: '15', busy: false},
                {from: '15', to: '16', busy: false},{from: '16', to: '17', busy: false},{from: '17', to: '18', busy: false},
                {from: '18', to: '19', busy: false},{from: '19', to: '20', busy: false},{from: '20', to: '21', busy: false},
                {from: '21', to: '22', busy: false},{from: '22', to: '23', busy: false},{from: '23', to: '00', busy: false},
            ], [ // Пятница
                {from: '00', to: '01', busy: false},{from: '01', to: '02', busy: false},{from: '02', to: '03', busy: false},
                {from: '03', to: '04', busy: false},{from: '04', to: '05', busy: false},{from: '05', to: '06', busy: false},
                {from: '06', to: '07', busy: false},{from: '07', to: '08', busy: false},{from: '08', to: '09', busy: false},
                {from: '09', to: '10', busy: false},{from: '10', to: '11', busy: false},{from: '11', to: '12', busy: false},
                {from: '12', to: '13', busy: false},{from: '13', to: '14', busy: false},{from: '14', to: '15', busy: false},
                {from: '15', to: '16', busy: false},{from: '16', to: '17', busy: false},{from: '17', to: '18', busy: false},
                {from: '18', to: '19', busy: false},{from: '19', to: '20', busy: false},{from: '20', to: '21', busy: false},
                {from: '21', to: '22', busy: false},{from: '22', to: '23', busy: false},{from: '23', to: '00', busy: false},
            ], [ // Суббота
                {from: '00', to: '01', busy: false},{from: '01', to: '02', busy: false},{from: '02', to: '03', busy: false},
                {from: '03', to: '04', busy: false},{from: '04', to: '05', busy: false},{from: '05', to: '06', busy: false},
                {from: '06', to: '07', busy: false},{from: '07', to: '08', busy: false},{from: '08', to: '09', busy: false},
                {from: '09', to: '10', busy: false},{from: '10', to: '11', busy: false},{from: '11', to: '12', busy: false},
                {from: '12', to: '13', busy: false},{from: '13', to: '14', busy: false},{from: '14', to: '15', busy: false},
                {from: '15', to: '16', busy: false},{from: '16', to: '17', busy: false},{from: '17', to: '18', busy: false},
                {from: '18', to: '19', busy: false},{from: '19', to: '20', busy: false},{from: '20', to: '21', busy: false},
                {from: '21', to: '22', busy: false},{from: '22', to: '23', busy: false},{from: '23', to: '00', busy: false},
            ], [ // Воскресенье
                {from: '00', to: '01', busy: false},{from: '01', to: '02', busy: false},{from: '02', to: '03', busy: false},
                {from: '03', to: '04', busy: false},{from: '04', to: '05', busy: false},{from: '05', to: '06', busy: false},
                {from: '06', to: '07', busy: false},{from: '07', to: '08', busy: false},{from: '08', to: '09', busy: false},
                {from: '09', to: '10', busy: false},{from: '10', to: '11', busy: false},{from: '11', to: '12', busy: false},
                {from: '12', to: '13', busy: false},{from: '13', to: '14', busy: false},{from: '14', to: '15', busy: false},
                {from: '15', to: '16', busy: false},{from: '16', to: '17', busy: false},{from: '17', to: '18', busy: false},
                {from: '18', to: '19', busy: false},{from: '19', to: '20', busy: false},{from: '20', to: '21', busy: false},
                {from: '21', to: '22', busy: false},{from: '22', to: '23', busy: false},{from: '23', to: '00', busy: false},
            ]
        ],
        autoVariations: [
            {name: 'Свой автомобиль', active: false},
            {name: 'Арендованный автомобиль', active: false},
        ],
        currentAutoVariation: -1,
    }
},
computed: {
    activeDayList () {
        return this.days.filter (day => day.active)
    },
    profitComment () {
        if (this.currentAutoVariation == -1) return '';
        else {
            if (this.currentAutoVariation.name == 'Свой автомобиль' ) return `Ваш ориентировочный доход за неделю составит: ${this.sumOwnCar} рублей.`
            else  return `Ваш ориентировочный доход за неделю составит: ${this.sumRentedCar} рублей.`
        }
    },
    sumOwnCar() {
        let sum = 0;
        for (let day = 0; day < this.days.length; day++) {
            if (!this.days[day].active) continue;
            for (let val = 0; val < this.globalIntervals[day].length; val++) {
                if (!this.globalIntervals[day][val].busy) continue;
                sum += this.getProfitPerIntervalByOwnCar(day,val);
            }
        }
        return sum;
    },
    sumRentedCar(){
        let sum = 0;
        for (let day = 0; day < this.days.length; day++) {
            if (!this.days[day].active) continue;
            for (let val = 0; val < this.globalIntervals[day].length; val++) {
                if (!this.globalIntervals[day][val].busy) continue;
                sum += this.getProfitPerIntervalByRentedCar(day,val);
            }
        }
        return sum;
    },

},
methods: {
    getCarVarationClass (variation) {
        return variation.active? "active list-group-item list-group-item-action" : "list-group-item list-group-item-action";
    },
    carVariationSelectHandler(variation) {

        if (this.currentAutoVariation == -1) {
            variation.active = true;
        } else {
            this.autoVariations[0].active = !this.autoVariations[0].active;
            this.autoVariations[1].active = !this.autoVariations[1].active;
        }
        this.currentAutoVariation = variation;
    },
    getProfitPerIntervalByOwnCar(day, val){

        const costs = [
            // ПН
            [500,500,300,300,300,300,300,460,460,380,380,340,340,340,340,340,360,400,400,360,350,350,380,380],
            //ВТ
            [320,320,270,270,270,270,270,380,380,330,330,300,300,300,300,300,320,370,340,330,350,350,370,370],
            //Ср
            [350,350,300,270,270,270,270,380,380,330,330,300,300,300,300,300,320,370,340,330,350,350,370,370],
            //ЧТ
            [330,330,270,270,270,270,270,400,400,330,330,300,300,300,300,300,320,370,340,340,350,350,370,370],
            //ПТ
            [330,330,300,300,300,300,300,380,380,360,360,320,320,320,320,360,360,360,400,400,400,400,400,400],
            //СБ
            [400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,350,350,320,320,320,320,350,350,390,390,430,430,430,430,430],
            //ВС
            [500,500,500,500,500,320,320,400,400,300,300,350,350,350,350,350,350,400,400,430,430,430,430,430]
        ];

        switch (day) {
            case 0:     return costs[0][val];// ПН
            case 1:     return costs[1][val];// ВТ
            case 2:     return costs[2][val];// СР
            case 3:     return costs[3][val];// ЧТ
            case 4:     return costs[4][val];// ПТ
            case 5:     return costs[5][val];// СБ
            case 6:     return costs[6][val];// ВС
        }
    },
    getProfitPerIntervalByRentedCar(day, val){
        const costs = [
            // ПН
            [500,500,330,330,330,330,330,460,460,380,380,370,370,370,370,370,390,400,400,390,380,380,400,400],
            // ВТ
            [350,350,300,300,300,300,300,380,380,370,370,340,340,340,340,340,340,380,380,350,380,380,400,400],
            // СР
            [400,400,300,300,300,300,300,380,380,350,350,330,330,330,330,330,340,370,370,350,380,380,400,400],
            // ЧТ
            [380,380,300,300,300,300,300,400,400,350,350,330,330,330,330,330,340,370,370,370,380,380,400,400],
            //  ПТ
            [380,380,320,320,320,320,320,380,380,360,360,350,350,350,350,360,360,360,400,400,400,400,400,400],
            // СБ
            [400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,380,380,350,350,350,350,380,380,390,390,430,430,430,430,430],
            // ВС
            [500,500,500,500,500,340,340,420,420,350,350,380,380,380,380,380,380,400,400,430,430,430,430,430]
        ];

        switch (day) {
            case 0:     return costs[0][val];// ПН
            case 1:     return costs[1][val];// ВТ
            case 2:     return costs[2][val];// СР
            case 3:     return costs[3][val];// ЧТ
            case 4:     return costs[4][val];// ПТ
            case 5:     return costs[5][val];// СБ
            case 6:     return costs[6][val];// ВС
        }
    },
    removePicker(event) {

        let removeIndex = -1;
        for (let i =0; i < this.globalDatePickerInfo; i++) {
            let obj = this.globalDatePickerInfo[i]
            if (obj.id == event.id && obj.day == event.day) removeIndex = i;
        }
        this.globalDatePickerInfo.splice(removeIndex, 1);
        this.updateGlobalIntervals();
    },
    updateGlobalIntervals () { // todo

        for (let i = 0; i < this.globalIntervals.length; i++)
            for (let j = 0; j < this.globalIntervals[i].length; j++)
                this.globalIntervals[i][j].busy = false; // сбрасываем выбор

        for (let i = 0; i < this.globalDatePickerInfo.length; i++) { // обновляем данные по всем пикерам
            //if (this.datePickerInfo[i].from == -1 || this.datePickerInfo[i].to == -1) continue;
            let from = this.globalDatePickerInfo[i].from;
            let to = this.globalDatePickerInfo[i].to;
            let day = this.globalDatePickerInfo[i].day;
            for (let j = from; j <= to; j++) {
                this.globalIntervals[day][j].busy = true;
            }
        }
    },
    reserveTime(event) { // todo

        let activeFrom = event.activeFrom; // данные по новову выбору
        let activeTo = event.activeTo;
        let day = event.day;
        let id = event.id;

        let fromIndex = +activeFrom.slice(0,2); // перевод часов в индексы
        let toIndex = (activeTo == '00:00')? 23 : ((+activeTo.slice(0,2)) - 1);

        let obj = this.globalDatePickerInfo.find(item => ((item.id == id) && (item.day == day))); // получаем объект по данному пикеру
        if (!obj) {
            this.globalDatePickerInfo.push({from:fromIndex, to:toIndex, id:id, day:day});
        } else {
            obj.from = fromIndex; // сохраняем данные в глобальном хранилище
            obj.to = toIndex;
        }

        this.updateGlobalIntervals();
    },
    getDayClass (day) {
        return day.active? "active list-group-item list-group-item-action" : "list-group-item list-group-item-action";
    },
    daySelectHandler (day) {
        if (day.active) {
            day.active = false;
            this.globalDatePickerInfo = this.globalDatePickerInfo.filter( item => item.day != day.id);
        } else {
            day.active = true;
        }
    }
}
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="calc" class="col-12 text-center">
      <!-- Content here -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm alert alert-prymary" role="alert">
          День недели
          <p>(выберите дни в которые планируете работать)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm alert alert-light" role="alert">
          Время работы
          <p>(укажите один или несколько интервалы)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm alert alert-light" role="alert">
          Тип автомобиля
          <p>(выберите тип автомобиля)</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="list-group">
            <button v-for="day in days" type="button" :class="getDayClass(day)" @click="daySelectHandler(day)">@{{day.text}}</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm border-right border-left">
          <time-picker-group v-for="day in activeDayList" :key="day.id" :name="day.text" :day="day.id" @date-picked="reserveTime" @date-picker-remove="removePicker"></time-picker-group>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="list-group">
            <button v-for="variation in autoVariations" type="button" :class="getCarVarationClass(variation)" @click="carVariationSelectHandler(variation)">@{{variation.name}}</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm border-top mt-2 alert" role="alert">

          <div class="bordered-calc"><strong>@{{profitComment}}</strong><br> Реальный доход может быть и выше, если в течении значительной части времени, которое вы посвятили работе, были неблагоприятные погодные условия, что соответственно повлекло повышенный спрос на такси и
            соответствующие высокие надбавки к тарифам.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Как перенести все данные из калькулятора VueJS в MYSQL ?

Comment: Ну, напрямую через VueJS у Вас не получится получить/внести данные в БД. Вы должны обратиться к серверу, как вы и говорили, у Вас там Laravel и уже вносить изменения в БД.

Comment: @NaClnik, А есть ли возможность упростить ввод данных? Или мне необходимо будет строить запросы через "Отношения" между моделями. Из-за большого кол-ва данных не очень удобно вводить всё в ручную.
У меня уже на сайте была страница которую пришлось реализовать самым наверное глупым образом это создать БД В которой было 31 поле. Каждое поле имело своё значение и менялась через БД, но это очень не удобно к сожалению делать.

Comment: @Yura_Lons Для того, чтобы не писать данные вручную, Вы можете использовать механизм сидеров в `Laravel`. Позволяют программно заполнять базу данных, вот ссылочка из документации `Laravel` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding#writing-seeders

Comment: @NaClnik, дело в том что эти данные необходимо будет заполнять через каждые 2 недели, и разницы в том что я буду заполнять их при помощи редактора непосредственно в файле калькулятора, и наполнять так же в файле при помощи сидов нету. Хотелось бы узнать как такую информацию добавлять непосредственно из админ-панели сайта, так чтобы не приходилось лесть на хостинг и менять(обновлять) файлы.